# cxgrid Group summary positioning

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, tcxgrid

Can anyone help me how I can shift the summary datas a bit right? I would like to put the summary, count data under the "issue" column. I use TcxGrid with groupsummaryitems.

The dxDBGridTableViewCustomDrawGroupSummaryCell event is probably suitable with using canvas to shift the values. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'd ask the DevEx support.

Comment: Changing `OptionsView.GroupSummaryLayout` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Changing groupsummarylayout to gslAlignWithColumns solved the problem.